# Convert Character array to integer array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, char, int

how to convert

```
char* string=new char[Length];
```

to

```
int* integer=new int[Length];
```

means
how to convert string to Integer in top codes

Comment: To convert a C string to int you can use [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/). But what does your string  look like, since you want to convert it to `int[]`?

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking. Can you please include an input string and an expected output integer array. Finally what is top codes?

Comment: @mary  What are "top codes"? Show an example of the conversion.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Does the string represent an integer? If it does, why does the result contain more than one integer? If it doesn't, what do you mean by "convert"?

Answer (score 1):

To convert a whole string into one number (maybe that is you really want?) you should use `atoi()` function

If you want an array of numbers then you can just make a simple loop

```
for (int i=0; i < Length; i++)
    integer[i] = string[i] - '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have code, that explicitly says, what you are doing.

```
std::transform(std::begin(string), std::end(string),
               std::begin(integer), [](const char& c) -> int {
                                        return c - '0';
                                    });
```

The compiled code should be the same as in Ilyases answer. The difference is about stating the intent. His code says "iterate over `string` and do something", while mine says "transform the elements of `string` and write the result to `integer`"

BTW.: Please consider to use `std::vector<>` instead of legacy dynamic arrays. It saves you from having to do all the memory management, border checking, etc. yourself. Also avoid to use class names from the standard library as variable names, because it might lead to confusion. `string` is not a good name for a variable, `integer` is neither, bit at least it is different from the typename `int`.

```
auto myInputStr = std::vector<char>(Length);
auto myInputAsInts = std::vector<int>(Length);
```

If `myInputStr` actually is a string, not just an ordered collection of otherwise unrelated characters, prefer `std::string` over `std::vector<char>`. The usage of `std::transform()` is the same as above, no matter, if you use `std::vector<char>` or `std::string`.

```
std::transform(std::begin(myInputStr), std::end(myInputStr),
               std::begin(myInputAsInts), [](const char& c) -> int {
                                              return c - '0';
                                          });
```