# How to change a character array to an integer array?

Tags: c++

Can someone explain to me why this doesn't work? I'm trying to change my array from a character to an integer array I've tried many ways but I can't figure it out. I saw that you can change a character to an integer is by C = I but when I tried to do it for an array it didn't work.

```
for(int i; i < size; i++)
    {
        h = characterarray[i];
        b = h;
        integerarray[i] = b;
    }
```

I also tried this but it didn't work

```
for(int i; i < size; i++)
        integerarray[i] = characterarray[i];
```

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: @jkb I'm trying to get all my characters in an array to go to an array of type int (assuming all the the characters are digits of course)

Comment: Hi, you can find the similar question that is answered in stack overflow. Please go through the below link. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719343/convert-character-array-to-integer-array-in-c)

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. You say it doesn't work but you don't tell us what about it that doesn't work.

Comment: @jkb both don't change the digits from a character array into an integer array.

Comment: It's not clear in your question, but now I'm assuming that `characterarray` contains character representations of digits, such as `'1'` rather than the numeric values. Try aubtracting`'0'` from the character.

Comment: @jkb sorry about that and I think I tried to do that earlier and it didn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Character array to integer array in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719343/convert-character-array-to-integer-array-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this-

```
for(int i; i < size; i++)
        integerarray[i] = characterarray[i] - '0';
```

Comment: this didn't do anything but thank you for trying

Comment: Use std::strtol Function to Convert Char Array to an Int. [link](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/cpp/how-to-convert-char-array-to-int-in-cpp/)